# How to perform keyword matching score of two different pdf documents?

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, spacy, word2vec, cosine-similarity

I could find n no. of documents, links for the sentence matching score but I need custom keyword matching score where I can extract keywords from 1 document and compare it with 2nd document. 
I have tried

```
import spacy 
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")

doc1 = nlp(text)
doc2 = nlp(text2)
doc1.similarity(doc2)
```

Output: 0.956... 
Almost for every document it is showing 0.9 above scores even if both documents are not relevant.

Comment: This question is too general for SO.

Comment: Thanks for response, can you check again and suggest. I'm more of looking for keyword match score. thanks! :)

Comment: What do you mean by 'keyword match score'? Why are you seeking a 'keyword'-based approach in preference to some more generic document-to-document similarity? (Will users sometimes be querying by keywords? Do you need to report a doc's keywords separately?) What's the actual end-user/project goal you want such similarity to support? Are you sure your `text` and `text2` are just texts-of-words, rather than raw PDF bytes? Can you show some examplesof document texts where you're getting  unexpectedly-high, >0.9 similarities?

Comment: (Also, if you're confused by `spacy` similarities, you may prefer a `spacy` tag on your question to an `nltk` tag, as there's no evidence you're using `nltk` in your question/code.)

Comment: So basically, I extracted keywords based on my custom list from PDF-A and PDF-B (separately). Now I want to compare PDF-A with PDF-B and give a match score like how many keywords are matching with PDF-A in percentage.
Objective: these PDF's are Resumes, and looking for match % with the second resume.